# Load DLL in Netbeans

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to load the DLL files in Netbeans 7.0.1,

Code is

```
dll = (RRHFEK02DLL)Native.loadLibrary("RRHFEK02DLL.dll", RRHFEK02DLL.class);
utility = (Utilities)Native.loadLibrary("Utilities.dll",Utilities.class);
wraper =(RRHFEK02Wrapper)Native.loadLibrary("RRHFEK02Wrapper.dll", RRHFEK02Wrapper.class);
```

the first line has no error, this line was in provider's demo, now I want another two dlls to be load, I have added next two lines and also added dll files in library , but I got error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
Unable to load library 'Utilities.dll': The specified module could not
be found.
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
    at rrhfek02.RRHFEK02View.<init>(RRHFEK02View.java:87)
    at rrhfek02.RRHFEK02App.startup(RRHFEK02App.java:19)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I have pass out through same/related questions ,but did n't got solution.
So, Please provide me suggestion if any one has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the `.dll` extension (It is not required on Mac, if the extension is `.framework`. On my system, with my netbeans project folder structure:

> lib
>
> ```
> + src
> + EDSDK
>       -dll
>           -EDSDK
>       -headers
> +Other Files
> ```

Doing:

`this.EDSDK = (EdSdkLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("EDSDK/dll/EDSDK.dll", EdSdkLibrary.class`

loads it effectively. Before loading, can you try what `new File("RRHFEK02DLL.dll").exists()` returns. If `false`, then your path is wrong. If `true`, then issue is something else

Answer (score 0):

Remove `".dll"` in Java. That is:

```
dll = (RRHFEK02DLL) Native.loadLibrary("RRHFEK02DLL", RRHFEK02DLL.class);
utility = (Utilities) Native.loadLibrary("Utilities", Utilities.class);
wraper = (RRHFEK02Wrapper) Native.loadLibrary("RRHFEK02Wrapper", RRHFEK02Wrapper.class);
```

Don't modify your actual DLL files' name!

Comment: In the IBM blog ,They suggest to put the .dll extension to the windows platform.

Comment: @chintan remove `".dll"` in your Java, don't modify your actual DLL file.